# Standard Constructor with CPoint argument in MFC

Tags: mfc

How can I declare a standard constructor in MFC that expects a CPoint argument, e.g.

```
class CObj {
public:
    CObj(CPoint pt = ???, float x = 10.0f, int n = 10);
    ...
```

I tried

```
CObj(CPoint pt = (10,10), float x = 10.0f, int n = 10);
```

which compiled just fine, but only pt.x got the value 10 while pt.y became 0.

Thanks, RS

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should work:

```
CObj(Cpoint pt = CPoint(10,10), float x = 10.0f, int n = 10);
```

Edit: It sure seems to work for me:

```
#include <iostream>

struct CPoint { 
    int x, y;
    CPoint(int x_, int y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}
};

class CObj { 
   CPoint p;
public:
   CObj(CPoint pt = CPoint(10,10), float x = 10.0f, int n = 10) : p(pt) {
       std::cout << "x.x = " << p.x << "\tx.y = " << p.y << std::endl;
   }
};

int main() { 
    CObj x;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
x.x = 10        x.y = 10
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Same result as with my approach: pt.x is 10, but pt.y is 0